# How to get the Ansinerator library to work?

Tags: php, apache, 8-bit, ansi-colors

I'm trying to get the Ansinerator library to work my on my localhost, but something's amiss.

I'm receiving the following errors:
`Notice: Undefined index: hash in ansi.php on line 23 Notice: Undefined index: aml in ansi.php on line 37 Notice: Undefined variable: PNG_DESTRUCT in ansi.php on line 119 Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in ansi.php on line 362 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ansi.php on line 362 Notice: Undefined variable: links in ansi.php on line 459 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ansi.php on line 677 Notice: Undefined variable: links in ansi.php on line 459 Notice: Undefined variable: map_link in ansi.php on line 687`

Any idea where am I going wrong with this one? I've installed the php-gd library, restarted the server, and while runs perfectly on production server, localhost will refuse. Ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check 
 - That you've got 'proper' versions of everything installed on localhost. (Compare localhost with production.) There's obviously something different between the 2 servers here, just use `phpinfo()` to check.

- Restart localhost again? (Just kidding...)

Comment: Could the reason be PHP 5.3.1?

Comment: It could, but I'd bet it's a good old case of sloppy coding. I haven't taken a look at the code, but those errors sound like they're the product of code that was written without E_NOTICE level errors enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have set different error reporting levels on both servers?

Before anything, put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script on both servers and see if it runs perfectly. (My guess is you will get errors on both servers)